# Rackspace Cloud Files API: 404 Error

Tags: php, api, file-upload, curl, rackspace

I'm using the following CURL request to post a file to Rackspace Cloud Files:

```
$ch = curl_init(trim($rackspace['X-Storage-Url']).'/container/hello');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Auth-Token: '.$rackspace['X-Auth-Token'], 'Content-Length: '.$data['file']['size']));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, fopen($data['file']['path'], 'r'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $data['file']['size']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

I'm following the Rackspace [documentation](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Create_Update_Object-d1e1965.html), but I'm getting a `404 Not Found` error and I'm not quite sure how to troubleshoot this. Any suggestions?

**SOLUTION**

After further analysis, I discovered that the X-Storage-Url that was issued after authenticating was `https://storage101.dfw1.clouddrive.com`. The **dfw1** indicates the data center in Dallas, but the containers I created were in Chicago. To confirm that this was the problem, I created a container at the Dallas data center and tried again – everything worked fine. I submitted a ticket to Rackspace to have my default storage location changed to Chicago. Everything is working now.

As pointed out in the selected answer, if I had been using the most up-to-date version of the API (2.0), then I would have been presented with URLs for both locations.

Comment: What is the URL you're generating? Does it work properly when you go there in your browser?

Comment: @andrewsi: When I paste the url directly into a browser, I get a `401 Unauthorized` error, which is expected since the `X-Auth-Token` isn't set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the old v1.0 authentication method as shown in the API docs [here](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Authentication-d1e639.html). Doing so will always return your default storage location. However, with v2.0 of the API auth system as described [here](http://docs.rackspace.com/servers/api/v2/cs-devguide/content/curl_auth.html), the [authentication response](http://docs.rackspace.com/servers/api/v2/cs-devguide/content/auth-response-description.html) will contain two different Cloud Files endpoint URLs, one for each data center. These both point to the same API, though, so all of your other Cloud Files-related code should "just work" if you swap out your authentication code.

Comment: I didn't even realize I was looking at the old documentation. I've moved to v2.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After further analysis, I discovered that the `X-Storage-Url` that was issued after authenticating was `https://storage101.dfw1.clouddrive.com`. The **dfw1** indicates the data center in Dallas, but the containers I created were in Chicago. To confirm that this was the problem, I created a container at the Dallas data center and tried again – everything worked fine. I submitted a ticket to Rackspace to have my default storage location changed to Chicago. Everything is working now.

Comment: I've moved this answer into the body of the question because I think it's important to note, but I'm going to choose GradysGhost's answer because he points out that if I had been using the new API, I wouldn't have run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A container with the name "container" needs to already exist under your account in the region your X-Storage-Url points at.  You're likely getting a 404 on the container, preventing the object from being created within it.  You can create the container via a PUT to the API or through the control panel at http://mycloud.rackspace.com/.

-Mark

Comment: Thanks Mark. I've already created a container via the control panel. I'm also able to upload files through the control panel. Any other ideas?